# Google Translate API のエラー　制限に関して

Tags: api, google-translate

Google Translate API　は1日の翻訳文字数に限度がありますが、この制約以外にも
短時間での制約があるなどということをご存知な方がいれば教えていただけませんでしょうか？

APIの設定を入れ、上限も料金を支払って底上げしているのですが、
英文3,000文字ほどを翻訳にかけるとlimit のエラーが返ってきてしまう状態です。

思い当たる節としては、1言語だけでなく63言語ほどこの3000語の文字を次々に翻訳にかけている
ので、もしかすると短時間に多言語翻訳する場合、制限があるのではと思っておりますが。

もし、このあたり、ご存知な方がいらっしゃればご教授頂けますと幸いです。
何卒宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

Google Developers ConsoleでTranslate APIのQUOTAタブにある、
「PER USER LIMIT」設定で１秒間あたりのリクエスト制限がかかっています。
短時間の連続実行で、この制約に引っかかっていないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。 確かにこの部分の設定は、デフォルトのままでした。
一度、設定を見直して再度翻訳チェックさせて頂きたいとおもいます。 ありがとうございました。

Comment: "ありがとう" を回答として追加しないでください。十分な[信用度](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)を獲得すれば、役に立つと思う[質問や回答に賛成投票を入れる](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)ことができます。